# How would I go about sorting details by date in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Essentially what I want to do is save details such as date, name, phone number,instructors name to a csv .txt database.
Then I want compare and sort these details with a bubble sort and display the closest date first, in ascending order.
How would I go about this?

Comment: Wouldn't using a db even something like SQL server Express would be a better option?

Comment: It's a school project, unfortunately we have to use basic stuff.

Comment: Are you allowed to use .NET sorting features or do you have to write sorting by hand?

Comment: Create a class to represent one record (line) in the CSV.  Parse the CSV into a collection of said classes.  Then implement a bubble sort on the collection.

Comment: BTW, you've already asked this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/18554509/745969 - and got 2 answers.  Was there a particular reason either of those answers didn't work for you?  Asking the same question multiple times on SO is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Date and DateTime variables with standard operative (<,=,>) I think less than (<) means earlier date, so if `foo`= August 3, 2013 and `foo2` = August 7, 2013

```
if foo < foo2 then
```

Would return true. You could use this to sort your times. There might be a function included in VB that would make it easier, I'm not a super VB expert.